# Is there any way to use doubles for x and y values in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, double, java-2d

I'm making a mini game where the player is a ball in the middle of the screen and shoots bullets guided by the mouse. I thought in order to guide the projectiles I could work out the gradient between the player and the mouse click, and increase the x and y values of a small rectangle by the gradient incrementally, at every paint. The problem with this however, is that 9 times out of 10, the gradient is a fraction, and is therefore impossible to use since x and y requires an int. Are there any possible workarounds or is this task simply impossible..?

Comment: Interesting I did something like that the other day on www.codingame.com but the usual solution would be to work out the hypotenuse for the triangle as you stated, remember you can cast back to int for use.

Comment: `Line2D` supports `double`s, as does `Point2D`. I would suggest having a look at [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html), but basically the 2D Graphics Shape's API works with `double`s (and `float`s)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would rather use a rectangle than draw a line to the enemy though since I'd like to have bullet travel time, and use if(bullet.intersects(enemy))

Comment: `Rectangle2D`, return the link, have a look at the JavaDocs

Comment: @MadProgrammer I went back and had a proper look. Sorry about my ignorant response, your comment did solve my problem, but I forgot to credit you. The game is finished now and the Rectangle2D.Double object allowed me to complete it, so I just wanted to thank you :), even though I asked this a while ago.